# How can I hide this button in ASP.NET getting value from Method?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a button in HTML like this:

```
<button id="EditTemplate" value="<%=this.GetUrlEncode() %>" class="btn-primary" type="button">
<em class="fa fa-edit"></em>Edit template
```

Because I'm using the `Value="<%=this.GetUrlEncode() %>"`, It can't have `runat="server"` as property because the button will not work. The problem is that I need to hide and show the button in c#:

```
this.EditTemplate.Visible = false/true;
```

It doesn't work because it needs to be `runat="server"`. Any ideas?

Comment: I could fix this, but I feel like I should ask for more information.  You are likely fighting another issue.

Comment: What information do you need?

Comment: What problem are you attempting to solve that led you to the above situation.

Comment: Agreed, not real sure what you are attempting to do.  But, you can always hide/show using Javascript (JQuery)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution by adding an attribute called value in the C# code like this

`EditTemplate.Attributes.Add("value", this.GetUrlEncode());`

so this let me to set `runat="server"` and still works